# Why use .pem certificate in apple push notification not p12

Tags: php, laravel, azure, pem, p12

I am creating a web portal using laravel framework to which one of its functionality is to send remote push notification on IOS App remotely. Many article in the internet is saying that we need the pem certificate file not p12. Why?

My co-worker who is developing the IOS mobile app, says that he is using the p12 certificate to get the push notifications from the Azure portal and successfully send push notification.

Is this because that he is pushing the app locally? Meaning the app directly sends  the notification? And I am pushing notifications remotely from the web portal? Is there any difference when pushing the app remotely and locally?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using Azure Notification Hubs. In [Azure's official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-ios-apple-push-notification-apns-get-started), they are obviously using the .p12 push certificate to configure authentication. So I think you don't need to worry to use it.

Comment: If thats the case, then how can I push a notification through the azure using the p12 certificate? Do you know some tutorials on how to achieve this one?